# Appropriate sql command to delete a row from table using form?

Tags: sql, forms, phpmyadmin

I want to delete one row from one of my tables, based on a form -> "username".Let's assume, i have a log in page, where i write into the fields the apropriate username, and password based on a database which contains these values.  After log in, i want to log out. And then I want to delete from the table the username and passwrod i used to sign in. How can i do it? Here's my code, it's unfortunately delete all the rows from the table. I have tried many ways... please help.

```
   $sql="DELETE FROM login WHERE username='username'" ;
   $result = mysqli_query($sqlconnection,$sql) or die...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume that you receive the username value by a form by post and assign the value to a vars

```
$username = $_SESSION['login_user'];
```

then you can pass the value to you query this way

```
$sql="DELETE FROM login WHERE username='$username';" ;

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to delete a record
$sql="DELETE FROM login WHERE username='$username';" ;

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Another fail.  Do you think the source of my problem this line? $username = $_POST['username']; The $username and the query are in a different file. Is it matter?

Comment: What do you mean with "$username and the query are in a different file "  The $username must contain a proper value for perform a correct delete  .. in someway you must have the correct value for this ..

Comment: It seems to me, that somehow the $sql doesn't recognise the value in $username. Sorry, I'm new in all these things. Are there any alternate way to do it?

Comment: $username=$_POST['username']; $username = stripslashes($username);  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);  $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; That's how my $username is built up

Comment: Answer update .. you can get the username from session

Comment: Can't believe it! It's finally working! You're awesome, thank you!

Comment: Thanks  hope is useful